# $\dim(W + U) = \dim(W) + \dim(U) - \dim(W \cap U)$ have a correlation with $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$ with the sets?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, soft-question, intuition, education

In mathematics, the *Grassmann formula* is a relation concerning the dimension of the vector subspaces of a vector space or of the projective subspace of a projective space.

We know that the enunciation Grassmann's formula is:

> Let $V$ a  vector space  on a  field $\Bbb K$ that have finite dimension. If  $W$ and $U$ be two subspaces of $V$ with $$W + U := \{\mathbf{w}+\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{w} \in W, \mathbf{u} \in U\}$$
> then
> $$\dim(W + U) = \dim(W) + \dim(U) - \dim(W \cap U) \tag 1$$

Obviously, if the sum is direct (I use the $\oplus$ symbol), then the intersection between the two subspaces consists only of the null vector ($W \cap U=\mathbf{0}$), hence

$$\dim(W \oplus U) = \dim(W) + \dim(U)$$

Now my question is indirectly for my **14-year old students** but it is useful for me if there is a relationship with the *Grassmann formula*. If I have any two sets $A, B$, it is very easy to verify with the examples that:

$$\bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]{|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|} \tag 2$$

But the $(2)$ has a correlation with $(1)$ and how you can adapt it to get a suitable answer-explanation very simple with an example?

Comment: Start with a basis for $W\cap U$.  It can be extended to a basis for $W$ and to a basis for $V$.  Then the union of those two sets gives a basis for $W+V$.  In this way the size of finite sets, counted by inclusion/exclusion, relates for us the dimensions of these vector spaces.

Comment: It is important to remember however that the result on dimensions of vector spaces does not generalise to the analogue of the three-set inclusion-exclusion statement

Comment: As Mike Daas points out the inclusion-exclusion principle doesn't work in general for vector spaces. There was some discussion of this problem [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17740/is-there-a-version-of-inclusion-exclusion-for-vector-spaces/26735#26735) years ago.

Comment: @hardmath Hi, I would be very happy to have an answer as simple as possible. I will inform you that it has been almost 28 years since I studied vector spaces. I still remember some of it and I should re-study it. I like linear algebra a lot. Thank you very very much.

Comment: @MikeDaas Hi, and excuse me for this short comment. It is similar to that of hardmath. I not remember (also for the my low level to use the English language to understand your assert  **It is important to remember however that the result on dimensions of vector spaces does not generalise to the analogue of the three-set inclusion-exclusion statement**. I hope in a short or concise simple answer.

Comment: @MatthewTowers Hi, I like linear algebra a lot but I always hope for the answers even if they were the simplest and most trivial so that I can understand better. I intuit the explanation in English through the formulas. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taught college linear algebra to qualified high school students, but a 14-year old would typically be a high school freshman.  I'd therefore try to frame the notions in concrete vector space terms, e.g. working with vector space $V$ consisting of tuples $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ of real numbers.

It is a *nice* property of finite dimensional vector spaces that their subspaces are again finite dimensional.  While one might be happy to "verify with examples" your statement (2), even to take this approach to the dimension of a sum $W+U$ of subspaces of $V$ will require familiarity with how dimension of a vector (sub)space is defined:

> The dimension of a vector space $V$ is $n$ iff $V$ has a basis set containing exactly $n$ vectors.

In other words one certainly needs to define a *basis* for a vector space, and to know pertinent facts about subspaces such as how a subspace is defined and:

- The intersection $W\cap U$ of two subspaces of $V$ is also a subspace of V.
- A basis for any subspace $W$ of finite dimensional $V$ can be extended to a basis for $V$.
- Every basis for subspace $W$ has the same size (so the dimension of $W$ is well-defined in not depending on the choice of a basis).

Let me dwell briefly on another crucial idea, the sum of two subspaces $W+U$.  There are two competing (but equivalent) ways to define this:

**(a)** The sum $W+U$ is the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ that contain both $W$ and $U$.

**(b)** The sum $W+U$ is the collection of all vectors in $V$ that can be expressed as $w+u$ for some $w\in W$ and $u\in U$.

In either case there is a bit work required to establish that $W+U$ is also a subspace of $V$.  It would then be possible to present the chain of ideas I laid out in my Comment.

1. The intersection $W\cap U$ is a subspace and has a finite basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$.  Thus $\dim(W\cap U) = k$, the size $k\ge 0$ of its basis.
2. This basis of $W\cap U$ can be extended to a basis $$\{v_1,\ldots,v_k,w_1,\ldots,w_\ell\}$$ of subspace $W$, and similarly extended to a basis $$\{v_1,\ldots,v_k,u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$$ of subspace $U$.
3. Finally, and the hardest part, one can show the union of those two basis sets $$\{v_1,\ldots,v_k,w_1,\ldots,w_\ell,u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$$ is a basis for $W+U$.  How one manages this depends on the pedagogical choice made to define $W+U$ discussed above.

In any case we can now compute the dimension of $W+U$ to be $k+\ell+m$, so that:

$$\dim (W+U) = (k+\ell) + (k+m) - k = \dim(W) + \dim(U) - \dim(W\cap U) $$

Comment: I thank you very much...$\infty$. Hence I can desume the $(2)$ using the $(1)$ as I thought. At least I didn't tell the students something wrong, and that gives me great encouragement. I will thank you once again.

Comment: Note the other Comments on your Question that point out the fragility of the relationship between (1) and (2). Although we laid out a proof sketch of (1) that uses (2) to count the size of a basis for $W+U$, the extension to more than two subspaces fails. The difficulty appears (when one proceeds naturally) because $X\cap(W+U)$ is generally not equal to $(X\cap W)+(X\cap U)$. In fact the latter expression may be the trivial subspace $\{0\}$ even when the former expression is all of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $W, U$ be the vector spaces formally spanned by $A, B$ respectively. Then $$\dim(W+U) = |A\cup B|, \dim(W) = |A|, \dim(U) = |B|, \dim(W\cap U) = A\cap B$$ therefore (2) formally follows from (1). But (1) is definitely a subtle and deeper result than (2).

Comment: What does "formally spanned by" mean? Because I'm thinking, what if $A = \{ v \}, B= \{2v \}$. (I think I know how to get around this with "free" constructions, but I doubt that OP would know, and I'm almost certain no 14-year old would.)

Comment: I agree this needs some clarification. But I believe you have probably underestimated humanity: I'm almost certain some 14-year old does.

Comment: Very kind user, thank you for your answer, but but the analogy to the cardinality of a set is the dimension in vector spaces is obvious. My question is how to properly understand the connection between the two relationships.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I agree with you about the very numerous difficulties and absence of knowledge about the science disciplines that 14 year old students have.