# Problems with the sets using the cardinality and the operations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, education, alternative-proof

> A survey shows that $63\%$ of kids
> like brand $A$ shoes and $76\%$ like brand $B$ shoes.
> brand $B$. Each boy in the group surveyed
> expresses at least one preference. Calculate the percentage
> of the boys who like both brand $A$
> and $B$ and the percentage of those who like only the
> $A$.

**My attemps**: I have thought that the total number $n_b$ of boys cannot obviously exceed $100\%$; but I have instead

$$|A\cup B|=63\%+76\%=\color{red}{139\%}$$

Subtracting the percentage of boys who like both brand $A$ and $B$ that is $100 \%$ I will have the percentage $n'$:

$$n'=\color{red}{139\%}-100 \%=39\%$$

After the percentage of those who like only the $A$ is:

$$|A - B|=|A|-|A\cap B|=63 \%-39 \%=24\%$$

**Question**: I have used the logic: surely the percentage of kids can't be more than $100\%$. Is there another motivation or is that the only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$|A\cup B|\equiv100\%,$$
since *everyone* must choose at least one option. The left-hand side equals
$$|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|.$$
Isolating $|A\cap B|$ then yields
$$|A\cap B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cup B|,$$
so
$$|A\cap B|\equiv63\%+76\%-100\%=39\%.$$
The way you computed $|A|$ is fine.

Comment: Very kind user here there was my old question :-) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272714/dimw-u-dimw-dimu-dimw-cap-u-have-a-correlation-with-a-c Thank you very much for your explanation and with bit of English language :-).